# datatables killing other scripts in php

Tags: javascript, php, scripting, datatables

I have the below scripts in the head of a php page that I am building:

```
<head>
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.0/css/dataTables.tableTools.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- jQuery -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- DataTables -->
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.0/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" ></script>

<script class="init" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75, -1], [25, 50, 75, "All"]],
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        tableTools: {
            "aButtons": [ "csv", "xls", "pdf" ],
            "sSwfPath": "//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.0/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "http://myIP/tools/ajax/snoozetable.php"      
    } );
} );
</script>

<script class="init" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text"  style="width: 40px;" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
        $( 'input', table.column( colIdx ).footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            table
                .column( colIdx )
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        } );
    } );
} );
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#Location').autocomplete(
            {source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({url: "//localip/tools/ajax/locs_by_name.php",
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        data: {term: request.term},
                        success: response
                        })
                },
             minlength: 2,
             select: function(event, ui) {
                    ui.item ? $('#locationid').val(ui.item.id) : $('#locationid').val('Error?');
                },
             open: function() {
                    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
                },
             close: function() {
                    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
                }
            })
            });
</script>
</head>
```

if i remove all of the other scripts, the $('#Location').autocomplete script works fine, but with all of the datatable scripts, it does not perform the autocomplete, though the datatable scripts all work.

any ideas why not??

requested edits:

```
<form method="post">
 <dl class="formbody">
 <table style="width:100%">
 <tr>
          <dt style="width: 200px;"><label for="Location">LocationName</label></dt>
          <dd><input tabindex="5" id="Location" class="fld" name="Location" type="text" value="<?php echo $Location; ?>" /></dd>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="80%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SnoozeID</th>
            <th>Side</th>
            <th>BlockType</th>
            <th>Partner</th>
            <th>Pattern</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            ..............
            ..............
            ..............
```

Comment: Pretty hard to simulate what you've got here, what does the developers console say? (Press F12 in webbrowser). Besides can you show your actual table?

Comment: i'm using firebug and it shows no errors or warning for the last script. the location field is part of a form and the datatable is below the form: `code`<form method="post">
 <dl class="formbody">
 <table style="width:100%">
 <tr>        <dt style="width: 200px;"><label for="Location">LocationName</label></dt>
              <dd><input tabindex="5" id="Location" class="fld" name="Location" type="text" value="<?php echo $Location; ?>" /></dd>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table></form><table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="80%">
        <thead>......

Comment: edit your question and put the table in there not in the comments.

Comment: the issue here was multiple instances of jquery messing with each other. I was able to fix this  by encapsulating the datatables scripts with jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) { .... }